# MongoDB trivial aggregation really slow

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have collection with URL views data contains ID of creator URL, datetime of visit, browser, referer, platform, device, etc... Now I want to make graph with visits by hour/day/month. I have index on field user (asc) and created (desc). In collection is something about 1.5M documents, in aggregation I count something about 800k documents but it took about 2 seconds! :/ Can you help me speed up aggregation? I have another aggregations for view visits by browser, platform, etc.. and its slow too. I'm thinking about saving counts by hour to external collection for graphs, what do you think?

Aggregation:

```
db.LinkView.aggregate([
    {
        "$match": {
            "created": {
                "$gte": new ISODate("2016-12-24T00:00:00"),
                "$lte": new ISODate("2017-01-02T00:00:00")
            },
            "user": ObjectId("585a7c2c1ccd5604f37238d2"),
        }
    },
    {
        "$group": {
            "_id" : {
                "year": {
                    "$year":"$created"
                },
                "month": {
                    "$month":"$created"
                },
                "day": {
                    "$dayOfMonth":"$created"
                },
                "hour": {
                    "$hour":"$created"
                }
            },
            "value": {
                "$sum":1
            }
        }
    }
], {
    explain:true
});
```

Explain:

```
{
    "waitedMS" : NumberLong(0),
    "stages" : [
    {
        "$cursor" : {
            "query" : {
                "created" : {
                    "$gte" : ISODate("2016-12-24T00:00:00Z"),
                    "$lte" : ISODate("2017-01-02T00:00:00Z")
                },
                "user" : ObjectId("585a7c2c1ccd5604f37238d2")
            },
            "fields" : {
                "created" : 1,
                "_id" : 0
            },
            "queryPlanner" : {
                "plannerVersion" : 1,
                "namespace" : "shortener.LinkView",
                "indexFilterSet" : false,
                "parsedQuery" : {
                    "$and" : [
                        {
                            "user" : {
                                "$eq" : ObjectId("585a7c2c1ccd5604f37238d2")
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "created" : {
                                "$lte" : ISODate("2017-01-02T00:00:00Z")
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "created" : {
                                "$gte" : ISODate("2016-12-24T00:00:00Z")
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "winningPlan" : {
                    "stage" : "PROJECTION",
                    "transformBy" : {
                        "created" : 1,
                        "_id" : 0
                    },
                    "inputStage" : {
                        "stage" : "IXSCAN",
                        "keyPattern" : {
                            "user" : 1,
                            "created" : -1
                        },
                        "indexName" : "analytics_all",
                        "isMultiKey" : false,
                        "isUnique" : false,
                        "isSparse" : false,
                        "isPartial" : false,
                        "indexVersion" : 1,
                        "direction" : "forward",
                        "indexBounds" : {
                            "user" : [
                                "[ObjectId('585a7c2c1ccd5604f37238d2'), ObjectId('585a7c2c1ccd5604f37238d2')]"
                            ],
                            "created" : [
                                "[new Date(1483315200000), new Date(1482537600000)]"
                            ]
                        }
                    }
                },
                "rejectedPlans" : [ ]
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "$group" : {
            "_id" : {
                "year" : {
                    "$year" : [
                        "$created"
                    ]
                },
                "month" : {
                    "$month" : [
                        "$created"
                    ]
                },
                "day" : {
                    "$dayOfMonth" : [
                        "$created"
                    ]
                },
                "hour" : {
                    "$hour" : [
                        "$created"
                    ]
                }
            },
            "value" : {
                "$sum" : {
                    "$const" : 1
                }
            }
        }
    }
],
    "ok" : 1
}
```